How do I find the optimal number of rounds needed so that my block cipher is secure?
I am new to cryptanalysis for SPN. In context of linear and differential cryptanalysis, I would like to know the following.

How does one find the number of active S-boxes in a block cipher?

Why does AES have 10 rounds as the optimal number of rounds? How did they arrive at this number?

Suppose I have a toy block cipher and I have its Difference Distribution Table (DDT). How do I find the optimal number of rounds required to secure my cipher?


Thank you very much.


Look at the network 2. know what you do, and look at possible attacks, 3. Did you start reading Hayes Linear Differential Tutorial?


Thank you Kelalaka. No, I haven't read  Hayes Linear Differential Tutorial. I will do that now.

There is also book of AES The Design of Rijndael: The Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)  that might help on your path.

thank you kelalaka.


Using Matsui's algorithm, one can find the highest probability trail and counting the number of $S$-boxes in the trail gives the active number.

Per the Rijndael specification document section 7.6



For Rijndael with a block length and key length of 128 bits, no shortcut attacks have been found for reduced versions with more than 6 rounds. We added 4 rounds as a security margin.

Note that this does not claim optimality.

Use Matsui's algorithm to find high probability trails through many rounds (based on both the difference distribution for difference attacks and linear approximation distribution for linear attacks); find ways to assume sub-exhaustive amounts of key to test these trails through inner rounds. Then use more rounds than the sum of the rounds in the trail plus the rounds short-cutted by the key assumptions. This will be a lower bound on the required number of rounds. It is hard to be assured of an upper bound on the required number of rounds as there may be other forms of attack (e.g. partitioning cryptanalysis, boomerang attacks, differential-linear cryptanalysis) or distinguishers that rely on "hulls" of multiple paths. Designers therefore tend to favour adding additional rounds to those required by the best-known attack as a "security margin".


Thank you Daniel. I would request you to briefly explain this from your answer  "find ways to assume sub-exhaustive amounts of key to test these trails through inner rounds."
